# When to specify PagingInfo.PagingCookie and PagingInfo.PageNumber

Tags: dynamics-crm, paging, fetchxml, query-expressions

Though reading lots of available resources online, I couldn't find a straight explanation that clarifies:

**In what case both the values of `PageingInfo.PageNumber` and `PageingInfo.PagingCookie` are required to be assigned?**

For example: Consider we have 10,000 unique records, and we'd like to retrieve all of them, but 200 records at a time. **Do we have to iterate over `PageNumber` (50 iterations), or is it enough to use only the `PagingCookie`?**

Now, I'd like to share what I've found on online resources:

Firstly, many online resources links to the official MSDN examples (For FetchXML: [1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328046.aspx), [2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309717.aspx), for QueryExpression: [1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt269606.aspx), [2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327917.aspx)), but there isn't a direct answer for this issue. They all iterate over the `PageNumber`, but as I understand (and it may be wrong), a Page *always* has 5000 records (Or is it?).

Secondly, I've found [this](https://truenorthit.co.uk/2014/07/19/dynamics-crm-paging-cookies-some-gotchas/) demonstration of using `PagingCookie`, fetching *records 6-10 out of 40 records*:

```xml
<fetch mapping="logical" count="5" page="2" paging-cookie="&lt;cookie page=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;new_parentrecordid last=&quot;{F8DAB1AA-3A0F-E411-8189-005056B20097}&quot; first=&quot;{F8DAB1AA-3A0F-E411-8189-005056B20097}&quot; /&gt;&lt;/cookie&gt;" version="1.0">
    <entity name="new_parentrecord">
        <attribute name="new_name" />
        <link-entity name="new_childrecord" from="new_parentaid" to="new_parentrecordid">
            <attribute name="new_childrecordid" />
            <attribute name="new_name" />
        </link-entity>
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

Then, it's explained that the above is translated to the following SQL query:

```sql
select top 6 "new_parentrecord0".new_name as "new_name"
            , "new_parentrecord0".new_parentrecordId as "new_parentrecordid"
            , "new_childrecord1".new_childrecordId as "new_childrecord1.new_childrecordid"
            , "new_childrecord1".new_name as "new_childrecord1.new_name" 
from
     new_parentrecord as "new_parentrecord0" 
    join new_childrecord as "new_childrecord1" on ("new_parentrecord0".new_parentrecordId  =  "new_childrecord1".new_ParentAId) 
where
     ((("new_parentrecord0".new_parentrecordId > '01DBB1AA-3A0F-E411-8189-005056B20097'))) 
order by
     "new_parentrecord0".new_parentrecordId asc
```

Thus, as I see it in this example, *there is no need to use the page number, since only the paging cookie is being used in resulted the SQL query*.

Would be great to have a nice clarification for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience and additional research I just did indicates that yes, we do need to iterate over all the pages. While the page number never makes it into the SQL query, it controls which ID SQL will use in its filter.

Without page # in the query:

[image: ss1]

The ID's in the paging cookie stay the same:

[image: ss1]

With page #:

[image: ss3]

The ID's change:

[image: ss4]

It is also interesting to note that if you advance the page # without changing the page or ID's in the paging cookie,

[image: ss5]

The system uses the paging cookie's last ID and expands the SQL "top" parameter to get the number of pages you requested:

[image: ss6]

And it must do some processing on the SQL recordset because it returns the right number of records (in this case 20), with the ID's advanced:

[image: ss7]

Comment: Aron, based on your answer, would it be true to say that `PageNumber` is actually the equivalent of LINQ `Skip()` function? If so, the number of records per "page" is the value assigned to `PageNumber`, right?

Comment: The number of records per page is the Count in the fetch header. PageNumber * Count is the number of records it skips.

Comment: So why initializing PageNumber to 1 (as in the MSDN examples) takes the first X records? Shouldn't it skip over the 1 * Count records?

Comment: actually it is (PageNumber-1) * Count, which is why when I had `count=20` and `page=10` it pulled 181 records. (maybe it pulls 181 instead of 180 to get the next guid for the paging cookie...)

Comment: I'm sorry, I feel I miss something: If `Count=20` and `PageNumber=10`, then shouldn't it have been (to use a LINQ equivalent)  `Skip(180).Take(20)` (and considering it takes plus 1 record: `Skip(180).Take(21)`)?

Answer (score 0):

The *PagingCookie* is a read-only identifier for the resultset the server has delivered to the client. Its purpose is to optimize data retrieval and should not be modified. The *PagingCookie* basically tells the server where the start and end of the page specified can be roughly found.

I assume it enables the CRM server to use cached query result sets. When paging through a result set using paging cookies I noticed the server only submits the SQL query once (i.e. when it receives a query without a paging cookie) and delivers subsequent pages - whenever possible - from memory.

The client is expected to simply copy the cookie into the *FetchXML* or *QueryExpression* when retrieving another page of the same resultset.

As far as I can see (testing it on Dynamics CRM 2016 (V8.2) this also works with joins.

I suspect the SQL query you are showing is actually the result of tampering with the PagingCookie: the server cannot find the cookie in its cache, assumes that the original resultset has been flushed and when it builds a fresh SQL query it fully relies on the correctness of the boundaries declared by the cookie. Hence the unexpected `where` clause.

#### Conclusion

Always use the `page` attribute (`FetchXML`) or `PageInfo.PageNumber` property (`QueryExpression`). Never modify the *PagingCookie*, just copy it into subsequent page requests.

When the page size (`count` attribute) is not specified it defaults to a maximum of 5,000 rows. When the expected result set is larger than that, you need to iterate all available pages.

When you are working with Dynamics CRM On Premise, you can modify the maximum page size using a PowerShell command.